# GWT: Event fired multiple times onClick

Tags: events, gwt, onclick

I need to get an event fired after clicking on a grid cell. It works but fires multiple events.
My Code:

```
private void gridClickHandler(final boolean cardDeterminer) {
    gridClickHandler = new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            int cellIndex = view.getGrid().getCellForEvent(event)
                    .getCellIndex(); // get clicked cell of grid
            if (cardDeterminer)
                oasisCardRPC(cellIndex); //rpc based on clicked cell
            else
                desertCardRPC(cellIndex); //rpc based on clicked cell

        }

    };
    view.getGrid().addClickHandler(gridClickHandler);
}
```

The method gridClickHandler is called in an onSuccess of a RPC and calls a new RPC using a boolean passed. (it works like this: click on some widget, when success then click on grid. Grid should only fire event, when this some widget was clicked directly before)
 I don't know how to create a new ClickHandler only once for the grid and still make its clickHandler only fire events, when needed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean : isClickHandlerAttached

Initially false, first time you add the clickhandler put it on true. Only attach if boolean is false.